# Python datetime from gps to local timezone not changing

Tags: python, datetime, gps

So I've been looking for a working solution, but I can't just find it...

I currently have a little program which fetches data from my serial device. This works 100%, but I have trouble with some datetime stuff....

The date and time is in UTC, but I want it in another timezone (`Europe/Brussels`).

Now, I have written some code that works to convert the input strings, but when I try to replace the data in my json with new data, it doesn't do anything...

Full code:

```
import serial
import string
import pynmea2
import datetime
import pytz
import math
import time

def utc_to_local(utc_date, utc_time):
    tz_eastern = pytz.timezone('UTC')
    tz_brussels = pytz.timezone('Europe/Brussels')
    return tz_eastern.localize(datetime.datetime.strptime(str(utc_date) + str(utc_time), '%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S')).astimezone(tz_brussels).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

def knots_to_km(knots):
    return round(math.floor(knots * 1.852))

def open_serial_connection():
    ser = serial.Serial()
    ser.port = "/dev/ttyS0"
    ser.baudrate = 9600
    ser.timeout = 1
    ser.open()
    return ser

def readGPS(serialObject):
    try:
        json = dict()

        latitude = 0.0
        longitude = 0.0
        speed = 0.0
        datetimestamp = ''

        sentence = serialObject.readline().decode('utf-8')

        if sentence.startswith('$GPGGA'):
            data = pynmea2.parse(sentence)
            latitude = data.latitude
            longitude = data.longitude

        if sentence.startswith('$GPVTG'):
            data = pynmea2.parse(sentence)
            speed = data.spd_over_grnd_kmph

        if sentence.startswith('$GPRMC'):
            data = pynmea2.parse(sentence)
            datetimestamp = utc_to_local(data.datestamp, data.timestamp)

        json["lat"] = latitude
        json["lon"] = longitude
        json["speed"] = speed
        json["time"] = datetimestamp

        if json["lat"] != 0.0 and json["lon"] != 0.0:
            return json
    except:
        pass

# Test code on pi
ser = open_serial_connection()
while True:
    data = readGPS(ser)
    if data is not None:
        print(data)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

The output here is the following:

`{'lat': xx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx, 'lon': x.xxxx, 'speed': 0.0, 'time': ''}`

The X-es are the correct Latitude and Longitude, they also change.

As you can see, the `time` is empty, but should change according to the code, right?

What am I missing here?

Comment: I think your `try` block masks some errors (possibly with the `utc_to_local` function).  In my own tests, I got something like: `ValueError: unconverted data remains: .710000`.  Also, only the `$GPRMC` sentence sets the time so it should be empty in all other cases.  You could also use `elif` and move `data = pynmea2.parse(sentence)` which is common to all cases right before.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean, but when I tried what you said, (I also removed the try catch) I don't have any error message here...

When the `datetimestamp` is printed in its if statement, I get `2019-09-01 01:38:47` (which is correct and converted)

Comment: [Edit] your question and show the output of `print(datetimestamp)` before `json["time"] = datetimestamp`

Comment: @stovfl my comment above yours states that output, but I"ll add it to the question for you...

Comment: ***"my comment above yours states that output"***: **No**, it's the output if the condition `.startswith('$GPRMC')` are `True`.

Comment: Okay, the output I get then are alot of blank lines and the datetimestap https://i.imgur.com/YroYiRM.png

Comment: Wy do you only set `datetime = ` inside `if .startswith('$GPRMC')`?

Comment: That is the only place I can get those values from. So I need to have it all separated in if-statemenst, no?

Comment: As I don't have access to your actual data stream I tried with this sample `$GPRMC` sentence: `$GPRMC,105320.71,A,0035.90592,S,00028.03281,W,0002.9,300.0,251211,0.0,W,A,S*6B` and it gives an exception when calling `utc_to_local` because of the `.71` of the first field, and if you mask the exceptions, the result is empty time like you observe.  If you remove `.71`, it parses OK, and the time string is displayed normally.  Maybe you've got something similar.  (I had to emulate the serial port with dummy data for testing as it's less practical to test directly on live constantly changing data.)

Comment: I'll post the working solution as an answer @stovfl helped me out, thank you alot!

Answer (score 0):

So the issue here was, as mentioned before, the `utc_to_local`, which wanted to parse "wrong" data and thus crashed the whole program...

Now the working code stays the same as before, except for the `readGPS()`, this has now a loop for the data, using a  `set()`:

```
def readGPS(serialObject):
    try:

        result = {}
        result_set = set()
        request_set = {'GPGGA', 'GPVTG', 'GPRMC'}

        while not request_set.issubset(result_set) and len(result_set) != 10:  # 10 == max sentences
            sentence = serialObject.readline().decode('utf-8')
            key = sentence[1:6]
            result_set.add(key)

            data = pynmea2.parse(sentence)

            if key == 'GPGGA':
                result["lat"] = data.latitude
                result["lon"] = data.longitude

            if key == 'GPVTG':
                result["speed"] = data.spd_over_grnd_kmph

            if key == 'GPRMC':
                result["datetime"] = utc_to_local(data.datestamp, data.timestamp)

        return result

    except:
        pass
```

It is also good practice to not just pass on errors, but log them or some kind of handling, but for my case, I don't really need to have error loggging (except in debugging), since I'll have alot of "wrong" responses.